# NoClassDefFoundError although Lib has imported correctly on Android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, libs

Heyho! I get a ClassDefFound error, when I want to call a function from an imported library.  I know, this is a issue which thousands of people got before, but i tried everything but it doesn't work! I'm using the android api level 17 with eclipse.

What I have tried:

- I added the library to the libs folder (like every other library i'm using)
- additionally I added the library to the build path (normally not necessary)
- I selected the library in Order and Export

  ```
  threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9e4d8908)
  FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-258
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: crs.kernel.model.db.RSDbSession
  at tsch.serviceApp.PageSystemApps$1$1.run(PageSystemApps.java:84)
  ```

Thank you everybody! I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Maybe your lib depends on another one? Which one are you talking about, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean And Compile/ Build the project again and then try.

If that doesn't work then try reverse engineering to see if the library is really added to your apk file.

1. Rename the apk file to have a .zip extension (As it is a normal zip file)
2. Extract the files, then try decompiling the classes.dex file and see if your class file is contained within it. I havent tried decompiling the dex file but there are tools outhere for example: 
   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2241002